# PHP Dom XML Not display value createElement

Tags: php, xml, dom

Create dom element like this

```
$SigningTime = $dom->createElement('xades:SigningTime','2021-02-25T12:57:51Z');
$SignedSignatureProperties->appendChild($SigningTime);
```

but the outout not disply the values

```
<xades:SigningTime/>
```

Comment: did you checked "view source" or "source" ? if you are running it in, Browsers automatically parsed XMLS

Comment: You are using namespaces so perhaps `createElementNS` and then save at the end of operations?

Comment: Not sure where the problem is supposed to be. https://3v4l.org/gHsWP

Comment: Is this your real code? How do you verify the output?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try after saving like this

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $element = $dom->createElement('xades:SigningTime', '2021-02-25T12:57:51Z');
    // We insert the new element as root (child of the document)
    $dom->appendChild($element);

    echo $dom->saveXML();
```